# ActiveRecord scope invocation test

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, mocking

I want to test/find out whether particular scope in my active record model was invoked during code fragment execution.

The standard way to check that via `ModelName.expects(:method_name).once` does not work for scopes defined within model. The query I am building adds/chains new scopes conditionally. It would be great to check how it was built without actually executing SQL query.

Comment: Try this `ModelName.send(:method_name).class.expects(:method_name).once`

Comment: I used scope name as :method_name and this is the result:


``NoMethodError (undefined method `expects' for MoneyTransaction::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class)``

Comment: @chumakoff, this suggestion does not work. It doesn't detect any invocations with rails 5. Not sure why op saw such error though.